# Create New User Display

Tags: 8

I am looking for a way to create new user Display.

When I go to Admin > Configuration > People > Acount Setting > Manage Dispaly

there are only three display modes: Default / Compact / User Account

How do I create a custom display mode?

See attached picture. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the page shown in the screenshot (*Administration > Configuration > People > Account settings > Manage display* or /admin/config/people/accounts/display) click on *Custom display settings*. It will show further settings, including the *Manage view modes* link.

> [image: screenshot]

Click on the *Add new mode* button.

> [image: screenshot]

Click on *User*

> [image: screenshot]

Enter the name for the new display mode, and click on *Save*.

> [image: screenshot]

When you go back to /admin/config/people/accounts/display, you will find the new display mode listed together the other ones.

Answer (score 2):

In drupal 8 you can easily create a new view mode via backoffice : Administration > Structure > Display modes > View > User
and click Add new User view mode. 
To go further see documentation : https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-api/display-modes-view-modes-and-form-modes